# How do I launch a particular version of illustrator from Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I have two versions of Illustrator installed, Adobe Illustrator 2020 and Adobe Illustrator CC 2019. How do I ensure from Applescript that the Adobe Illustrator CC 2019 is picked?

For that, i have did the following applescript coding, but the applescript automatically change the application name.

```
set theResult to every paragraph of (do shell script "mdfind 'kMDItemContentTypeTree == \"com.apple.application\"c' | sort")
set systemApps to {}
set applicationsApps to {}
set Version2019 to "" as string
set Version2020 to "" as string
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theResult
    set end of systemApps to item i of theResult
    
    if item i of theResult contains "Adobe Illustrator CC 2019" then
        set end of applicationsApps to item i of theResult
        set Version2019 to "true" as string
        exit repeat
    end if
    
end repeat
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theResult
    set end of systemApps to item i of theResult
    
    if item i of theResult contains "Adobe Illustrator 2020" then
        set end of applicationsApps to item i of theResult
        set Version2020 to "true" as string
        exit repeat
    end if
    
end repeat
--display dialog (Version2019)
tell application "Finder"
    
    if (Version2019 contains "true" and Version2020 contains "true") then
        --display dialog "hey! " & theUser & return & return & "Adobe Illustrator 2019 and Adobe Illustrator 2020 available in this Mac" buttons {"Ok"}
        set questionStudio to display dialog "hey! " & return & return & "Adobe Illustrator 2019 and Adobe Illustrator 2020 available in this Mac." & return & return & "Please select Version:" buttons {"Adobe Illustrator CC 2019", "Adobe Illustrator 2020", "Cancel"}
        set answerStudio to button returned of questionStudio
        
        if answerStudio contains "Adobe Illustrator 2020" then
            tell application "/Applications/Adobe Illustrator 2020/Adobe Illustrator.app"
                if it is not running then launch
            end tell
            it is running
            return 0
            
        else if answerStudio contains "Adobe Illustrator 2019" then
            tell application "/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC 2019/Adobe Illustrator.app"
                if it is not running then launch
            end tell
            it is running
            return 0
            
        else if answerStudio contains "Cancel" then
            tell me to quit
        end if
        
    else if (Version2019 contains "true") then
        --tell application "Finder"
        set appVersion to "Adobe Illustrator 2019"
        --end tell
    else if (Version2020 contains "true") then
        --tell application "Finder"
        set appVersion to "Adobe Illustrator 2020"
        --end tell
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: I have no experience with applescript but I notice you are missing the `CC` of the 2019 version in several places. If that `CC` is part of the name is it possible that this might be the reason why it isn't finding it and defaulting to 2020?

Comment: Thanks for checking and notify. Actually the Applescript automatically change the application name while compile the script, that is the main problem here. Apple script not allowed to specify the version in application Name. I am also new to this apple script, so i am not sure how to solve that. Please help me out from this if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Use the full path to the application, not just its name.

Also be aware that the application name displayed in Finder may not be its true file name.

Easiest way to get the app’s full path is just to drag-n-drop its icon into a Script Editor window.

Example:

```
tell application "/Applications/Adobe Illustrator 2020/Adobe Illustrator.app"
    …
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for checking. I used the same, but again i will recheck my script.